# How to remove options from a select box

Tags: jquery, html

What I want to do is that which ever options are display in the "#studentadd" select box, I want to be able to remove ALL matching options from the `#studentselect` select box as well as empty the `#studentadd` select box. But at the moment it is not doing this.

What am I doing wrong?

Below is html of both select boxes:

Below is the select box `#studentadd`:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="addtextarea" id="studentadd" size="10">
    <option value='1'>u08743 - Joe Cann</option>
    <option value='4'>u03043 - Jill Sanderson</option>
    <option value='7'>u08343 - Craig Moon</option>
</select>
```

Below is the select box the students should be appended into:

```
    <select id="studentselect" name="studenttextarea">
        <option value='1'>u08743 - Joe Cann</option>
        <option value='4'>u03043 - Jill Sanderson</option>
        <option value='7'>u08343 - Craig Moon</option>
</select>
```

Below is jquery:

```
$('#studentadd option').attr('selected', 'selected');

var selectedOption = $('select#studentadd');
$('select#studentselect').remove(selectedOption.html());
```

Comment: `selectedOption.empty();`

Comment: what do you mean by "empty the #studentadd select box"?

Comment: But do you need to retain the value of it?

Comment: I notice #studentadd is a multi select. Is it supposed to be? It might affect the answer given.

Comment: @popnoodles Yes its multi select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var selectedOption = $('#studentadd').find(':selected');
var studentSelect = $('#studentselect');
selectedOption.each(function(){
    studentSelect.find('[value="'+this.value+'"]').remove();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/jVj9j/)

Comment: why do you do this `$('#studentadd').find(':selected');` instead of `$('#studentadd :selected');`?

Comment: @popnoodles avoiding sizzle when selecting from the entire document.

Comment: @popnoodles sizzle is the jQuery css selector engine.

Answer (score 1):

It would try to rely on the value attribute, if you have the same data in both lists:

```
$('#studentadd').change(function () {  
  var value = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
  $('#studentselect option[value="' + value + '"]').remove();
});
```

// Update: Handle selection of multiple elements

```
$('#studentadd').change(function () {
  $(this).find("option:selected").each(function () {
    $('#studentselect option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').remove();
  });
});
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/EvpDx/2/

Comment: I still don't know what they mean by "empty the #studentadd select box"!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove selected items from SELECT (no matter - multiselect or sinlge), you may use:

```
$('#studentadd option').attr('selected', 'selected');  //Preparation
$('#studentadd option:selected').remove()              //Choose all selected OPTIONs from item with ID=studentadd and remove it
```

Comment: This has still not removed the options from the #studentselect

Comment: Sorry, mistyped. Correct expression is: 
`$('#studentadd option:selected').remove()`